# I need to create a SQL Server 2019 Express database from a SQL Server 2022 database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-express

I have developed a database in SQL Server 2022 (and have SSMS), I need to recreate and include all data from that database on a different server which contains SQL Server 2019 Express.

When in SSMS, I right click and do a restore it doesn't find my `.bak` file anywhere. I see the `.bak` file but it won't find it for me to select.

I have moved the filed to multiple locations all in the root of folders I see in the selection window but the file never shows for selection

I have also tried to do it via script

```
RESTORE DATABASE [new database name] 
FROM DISK = 'filelocation\filename.bak'
```

Can anything be done easily where the database gets created inclusive all of the data in each of the tables?

I did a restore through SSMS and a direct query and I was expecting that it would create the database, all of the tables.

I also created a new database and tried to restore the `.BAK` file to the newly created database it also didn't work.

Comment: You would not be able to `RESTORE` a 2022 database on a 2019 instance. Though, if you can't see the database backup, you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: You **CANNOT** go back from a newer version (2022) to an older version (2019) using `.bak` files. SQL Server isn't and has never been backwards compatible in that regard. You'll need to script out all your db objects into `.sql` files, and also script out the data into SQL files with `INSERT` statements (you can do this from SSMS)

Comment: Also, the Express edition has a file size limit of 10 GB - so if your original database is larger than this, you won't be able to get it up and running in an Express edition database.

Comment: UPDATE: for what its worth, the linked (duplicate) didnt help however. I did figure out how to do it. I simply saved each table as a CREATE query script individually and ran them one by one in EXPRESS , then for the data I did a task - > generate script options and then choose the to only include the DATA and it scripted all the insert records for me.. sadly I am have a problem with my larger datasets because they have over a mil records